# How can I grep recursively, but only in files with certain extensions?

Tags: grep

I'm working on a script to [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) certain directories:

```
{ grep -r -i CP_Image ~/path1/;
grep -r -i CP_Image ~/path2/;
grep -r -i CP_Image ~/path3/;
grep -r -i CP_Image ~/path4/;
grep -r -i CP_Image ~/path5/; }
| mailx -s GREP email@domain.example
```

How can I limit results only to extensions **`.h`** and **`.cpp`**?

Comment: Tried `grep -r -i CP_Image ~/path1/*.{h,cpp}`?

Comment: Use [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher): `ag -i CP_Image ~/path[1-5] | mailx -s GREP email@domain.com`. Job done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep --exclude/--include syntax (do not grep through certain files)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files)

Comment: Use egrep (is most likely pre-installed on your system), and then you can use a regex.

Comment: The GNU guys really messed up when they added `-r` to `grep` to have it search for files as that breaks the UNIX mantra of having tools that "do one thing and do it well". There's a perfectly good tool for finding files with a VERY obvious name.

Comment: @Dogweather , `egrep` has been deprecated for a long time. From `grep`'s man page: `Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.` To achieve the same result, one must use `grep -E`

Answer (score 1921, accepted):

Just use the `--include` parameter, like this:

```
grep -inr --include \*.h --include \*.cpp CP_Image ~/path[12345] | mailx -s GREP email@domain.example
```

That should do what you want.

To take the explanation from [HoldOffHunger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516937/how-can-i-grep-recursively-but-only-in-files-with-certain-extensions/35280826#35280826) below:

- `grep`: command
- `-r`: recursively
- `-i`: ignore-case
- `-n`: each output line is preceded by its relative line number in the file
- `--include \*.cpp`: all *.cpp: C++ files (escape with \ just in case you have a directory with asterisks in the filenames)
- `./`: Start at current directory.

Comment: @Hong where is the documentation that -R is for symbolic links?

Comment: Can someone explain why this syntax works as opposed to what's described in the man page `--include=GLOB`

Comment: This example seems to have a high score because it covers such a wide range of possibilites but the answer given below of  
   grep -r --include=*.txt 'searchterm' ./
really explains the essence of the answer

Comment: why not use double quotes instead of backslash?  e.g: `grep -r -i --include="*.h" --include="*.cpp" CP_Image `

Comment: @nelson How would you change this to just return all file extensions

Comment: Did *not* answer the question! Jasmine asked for *two* file types in a single search!

Answer (score 453):

Some of these answers seemed too syntax-heavy, or they produced issues on my Debian Server.  This worked perfectly for me:

```
grep -r --include=\*.txt 'searchterm' ./
```

...or case-insensitive version...

```
grep -r -i --include=\*.txt 'searchterm' ./
```

- `grep`: command
- `-r`: recursively
- `-i`: ignore-case
- `--include`: all *.txt: text files (escape with \ just in case you have a directory with asterisks in the filenames)
- `'searchterm'`: What to search
- `./`: Start at current directory.

Source: [PHP Revolution: How to Grep files in Linux, but only certain file extensions?](https://phprevolution.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-grep-files-in-linux-but-only.html)

Comment: You should escape the `*` using `\*.cpp` or `'*.cpp'`. Otherwise it won’t give the expected result when the working directory contains some `*.txt` files.

Comment: @Melebius can you explain why it needs escaping - does it have anything to do with the CPP or TXT extensions you mentioned? Or did you just use those as examples?

Comment: @SimonEast These extensions are those used in this question and answer, nothing special otherwise. It would probably work without escaping when using `--include=<pattern>` but it is important to escape `*` with `--include <pattern>` (a space instead of `=`) which feels very similar otherwise.

Comment: @Melebius adding to what you wrote, it does work with `--include=<pattern>`. It also works with `--include<pattern>`, so long as there are no files matching the pattern in the current directory. I.e., it's safest to escape the pattern when you're not using the `=` syntax, but you can live dangerously if you assume there are no files matching the pattern in the current directory.

Comment: Did *not* answer the question! Jasmine asked for *two* file types in a single search!

Answer (score 92):

```
grep -rnw "some thing to grep" --include=*.{module,inc,php,js,css,html,htm} ./
```

Comment: grep -rn "some thing to grep" --include=*.{module,inc,c,h} *

Comment: Nice answer.  Cleaner than the accepted on IMO but you should add search criteria as @ashish noted

Comment: why is `--include` option after needle, not with other options?

Comment: @vladkras, what do you mean needle? Is it `--`?

Comment: Almost, but that didn't work for me--it kept trying to match on `--include=*.foo`. The working solution was wrapping the `--include` value in quotes. E.g. `--include="*.foo"`.

Comment: @AlanHape `*` is a special character in shells: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755806

Comment: Good answer, but it will not work with only 1 extension like `--include=*.{php}`

Comment: Just like include is there a way to exclude list of extensions?

Answer (score 62):

Use:

```
find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' -exec grep "CP_Image" {} \; -print
```

Comment: i'd suggest grouping those `-name` arguments. strange things can happen if you don't. `find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec grep "CP_Image" {} \; -print`

Comment: use with additional "-type f" to ignore all directory objects, only interested in files.

Comment: I used this method for years and it works but it's a LOT slower than recursive grep since find's exec spawns a separate grep process for each file to be searched.

Comment: Addressing @beaudet's comment, `find` can optionally bundle arguments, reducing invocations of the called process to a minimum.

`find . \( -name \*.h -o -name \*.cpp \) -exec grep -H CP_Image {} +`

This is suggested but not highlighted in @fedorqui's answer below and is a worthwhile improvement.

The `-H` argument to grep here is useful when find only identifies a single matching file.  This could eliminate the usage of `-print` in the answer.

If your total list of files is sufficiently small, using a recursive shell glob (eg. `{path1,path2}/**/*.{cpp,h}`) might be preferable.

Answer (score 36):

There isn't any `-r` option on HP and Sun servers, but this way worked for me on my HP server:

```
find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep -i "my great text"
```

`-i` is for case insensitive search of string.

Comment: I've come across several servers for web hosting companies that do not have the --include option available for fgrep and this is the command line that I use in those instances.

Comment: The --include option is also not available when using Git for Windows (MinGW/MSys).

Comment: @DarrenLewis available in Git Bash for Windows. But strangely, it adds colorful aliases like `ll` but does not add `--color=auto` to grep.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for completeness, portability, and brevity!

Comment: Re *"HP and Sun servers"*: Do you mean for [HP-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX) and [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29)?

Comment: When there is a space character in the file name, it would be treated as two file names. Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: @hyz Use `find ... -exec grep "string" {} +` (or `\;` instead of `+` at the end if your `find` is too old to support `+`). See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 23):

This answer is good:

```
grep -r -i --include \*.h --include \*.cpp CP_Image ~/path[12345] | mailx -s GREP email@domain.example
```

But it can be updated to:

```
grep -r -i --include \*.{h,cpp} CP_Image ~/path[12345] | mailx -s GREP email@domain.example
```

Which can be simpler.

Comment: What does *"The below answer"* refer to? References to relative positions of answers are not reliable as they depend on the view (votes/oldest/active) and changing of the accepted answer and change over time (for votes, active, and accepted state). Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48533603/63550), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Can we simply use grep command along with ls command?

Comment: @Harsha Sure. use pipe to make the output of ls as the input of grep. such as        ls | grep *.h

Comment: Could you provide me a link that would give explanations as to how I can fully understand this?

Comment: @Harsha https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19504-01/802-5826/6i9iclf5k/index.html

Comment: note: you can combine single-letter options. `grep -r -i` is the same as `grep -ri`. I mention this because I often like to use other options like '-n' and '-H' so this becomes `grep -Hinr --include ...`

Answer (score 15):

Since this is a matter of *finding* files, let's use `find`!

Using GNU find you can use the `-regex` option to find those files in the tree of directories whose extension is either `.h` or `.cpp`:

```
find -type f -regex ".*\.\(h\|cpp\)"
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then, it is just a matter of executing `grep` on each of its results:

```
find -type f -regex ".*\.\(h\|cpp\)" -exec grep "your pattern" {} +
```

If you don't have this distribution of find you have to use an approach like [Amir Afghani's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12516997/1983854), using `-o` to concatenate options (*the name is either ending with `.h` or with `.cpp`*):

```
find -type f \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec grep "your pattern" {} +
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

And if you really want to use `grep`, follow the syntax indicated to `--include`:

```
grep "your pattern" -r --include=*.{cpp,h}
#                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I needed a script which returned exit status 1 if the grep command matched any files. I started out using find+xargs+grep. But the fact that xargs returns exit status 123 if grep returns 1 made things more complicated. It was more straightforward to just use grep in my case.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is:

```
find . -type  f -name '*.extension' 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -i string
```

Add `2>/dev/null` to kill the error output.

To include more file extensions and grep for password throughout the system:

```sh
find / -type  f \( -name '*.conf' -o -name "*.log" -o -name "*.bak" \) 2>/dev/null |
xargs grep -i password
```

Answer (score 5):

[`ag`](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) (the silver searcher) has pretty simple syntax for this

```
       -G --file-search-regex PATTERN
          Only search files whose names match PATTERN.
```

so

```
ag -G *.h -G *.cpp CP_Image <path>
```

Comment: using ag 2.2.0, i needed to put my flags last: `ag _string_to_find_  -G _filename_regex_`

Answer (score 2):

You should write "-exec grep " for each "-o -name ":

```
find . -name '*.h' -exec grep -Hn "CP_Image" {} \; -o -name '*.cpp' -exec grep -Hn "CP_Image" {} \;
```

Or group them by ( )

```
find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec grep -Hn "CP_Image" {} \;
```

Option '-Hn' shows the file name and line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I normally use to find **.c** and **.h** files:

```
tree -if | grep \\.[ch]\\b | xargs -n 1 grep -H "#include"
```

Or if you need the line number as well:

```
tree -if | grep \\.[ch]\\b | xargs -n 1 grep -nH "#include"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out extensions from the output of another command e.g. "git":

```
files=$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d origin/master... | grep -E '\.cpp$|\.h$')

for file in $files; do
    echo "$file"
done
```