# How to find out where a C struct is declared?

Tags: c, struct, types, polipo

I am trying to add logging to the web proxy Polipo and as part of this need to log the url request in the following function [following line](https://github.com/jech/polipo/blob/ab52932c20638491f696e256020ad6a20aad7939/client.c#L707):

```
httpClientRequest(HTTPRequestPtr request, AtomPtr url)
```

From compilation I see that AtomPtr is a struct of type `_Atom` but I cannot find where this is defined so that I can reference the text of the url in a log statement. What is the canonical method of looking up struct definitions in C code?

Comment: You need to search through the .h files. A grep tool is useful in such situations. Many IDE's offer this feature.

Comment: It depends on your system and environment. If you're using an IDE it usually have functionality to find definitions built-in. If you're using the command-line then there are commands that can be used to find text in a set of files (the name of the command depends on the operating system you use).

Comment: Compile with `-D_Atom=123` and see where the first error is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can search **AtomPtr** like [this](https://github.com/jech/polipo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=atomptr) and see where AtomPtr is defined

```
typedef struct _Atom {
    unsigned int refcount;
    struct _Atom *next;
    unsigned short length;
    char string[1];
} AtomRec, *AtomPtr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, you cannot do this *from the source code* in C.
If you are working on Linux, and if your sources are all in the `src/` directory:

```
$ find src/ -name ".*\.h" | xargs grep -e "struct _Atom"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Linux, then grep the *struct* keyword in the current directory to see the definition of it in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to look up the definition of a structure MenuType by

```
grep -Rwn --include \*.h "struct MenuType"
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516937/how-can-i-grep-recursively-but-only-in-files-with-certain-extensions) helped me.