# how to echo result of `find` to screen?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My intention is to search for a string in specific file format recursively in the current directory. From SO I found [this find command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42055104/6680585) to search

> find . -type  f -name '*.extension' | xargs grep -i string

But this was too lengthy and I found this really hard to remember. So, I tried to write a function and add it to my `.bash_profile` something like this

```
function search {
     echo `find . -type  f -name '*.$1' | xargs grep -ir '$2'`
}
```

and the other one which I've tried is

```
function search {
    echo `find . -type  f -name '*.$1' | xargs grep -ir '$2'`
}
```

Both didn't print any results on the screen when I invoke my as

`search txt mysearchstring` though I have few `.txt` files in the directory which contains the word `mysearchstring`. I'm not sure what makes me go wrong. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: double quote `$1` and `$2`

Comment: @Inian: Thanks for the suggestion Inian. It worked but it didn't preserve the new line character which `grep` provides. It presents entire result in a single line.

Comment: You don't need to `echo` inside the function (remove it), just have the `find` command alone. It will print its standard output to terminal

Comment: Hurrah !! It worked thanks @Inian.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify the `find ... | xargs grep ...` sequence with `find`'s `-exec` primitive: `find . -type  f -name "*.$1" -exec grep -ir "$2" {} +`. This also avoids parsing trouble with some weird characters in filenames.

Comment: Wow that sounds cool ! Thanks @GordonDavisson :)