# getting different output for character in Command line argument

Tags: java

```
print("First  name: +args[0]);
print("Middle name: +args[1]);
print("Last   name: +args[2]);


java Demo Hello 123 ***
Output is Hello 123 .local
```

I expect the output of `Hello 123 ***` to be `Hello 123 ***` but the actual output is coming as `Hello 123 .local`
How integer is giving same output,but `***` is giving as `.local`

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah but i am not able post the actual question

Comment: @Carcigenicate clas Demo
{
 public static void main(Strng[] args) 
{
System.out.println("First  name: +args[0]);
System.out.println("Middle name: +args[1]);
System.out.println("Last   name: +args[2]);`
 }
    }


java Demo Hello 123 ***
Output is Hello 123 .local

I expect the output of Hello 123 *** to be Hello 123 *** but the actual output is coming as Hello 123 .local
how inetrger is giving same output,but *** is giving as .local

Comment: @Carcigenicate do check the question and please answer the question if u know

Comment: you should be aware that `*`  is treated as special by some command line interpreter (replaced with list of files) so the actual line is like "java Demo Hello .local Demo.class Demo.java someOtherFiles..." - and still `print("First name: + args[0])` is never valid in Java

Comment: @Carcigenicate i am passing Hello 123 ***

Comment: try `echo *` (its not java, `echo` will print all given arguments)

Comment: To pass a literal `*`, escape it with `\*`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755803/1563833

Answer (score 3):

Your operating system uses the concept of pathname expansion. That means when you pass a wildcard `*` as a parameter it replaces it with any file. The first file found in your current directory is `.local`. 
To overcome it you have to quote that parameter and pass: `Hello 123 "***"`