# Why does asterisk (*) not pass as a normal character in String[] args?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem of * in Command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718873/problem-of-in-command-line-argument)

I've written a simple attempt at a small calculator which does 4 operators (+,-,* and /).

When I pass any other 3 operator to my program through the command line, "java Calc 4 + 4", it works. However, when I tried passing "4 * 4" I get a reference to a Class.class - why is this objectified instead of being handled as a normal string? What is happening here?

Is it something to do with the Windows command line using the * as wildcard? If so, how can I get around this?

For now, as a simple fix, I've written the operator multiplies as the character 'x'.

TIA

Comment: Well spot @Joachim Sauer this should be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try surrounding the * with quotes like **"*"**. The * is a reserved symbol on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The shell replaces * with the list of the files in the current directory. Use single-quotes to pass the asterisk: '*'.

Answer (score 0):

Because asterisk is OS depends char which means all files, so you must escape asterisk