# Why is Windows injecting my directory listing into argv when I use **?

Tags: c++, windows, file, operating-system, argv

Here's the following main method:

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    std::string expression=argv[1];
    for(int i=2;i<argc;i++)
    {
        expression+=' ';
        expression+=argv[i];
    }
    std::cout << expression << std::endl << std::endl;
    Expression* expr = Expression::build(expression.c_str());
    std::cout << expr->evaluate() << std::endl;
    delete expr;
    return 0;
}
```

Which, for some reason works great most of the time, but see this input / output examples:

```
D:\Tyler\Desktop>a 2**3
2**3

8

D:\Tyler\Desktop>a 2 ** 3
2 10284556_10203827451228798_9031461414658797199_o.jpg 15686-vanille.p3t 18
865-MiraiNikki.p3t 20777-MIRRORSEDGE2AnimatedTheme.p3t [APE] gras.gpl [Irfa
nView] [APE] gras.pal a.exe arboles_FM.png calc.c calc.cpp couch.png deskto
p.ini gras.pal hackzorz log.txt montanas_FM.png p3textractor p3textractor.z
ip PALLET TOWN.bmp PALLET TOWN.png Pokemon FireRed.bak Pokemon FireRed.gba
Pokemon FireRed.ini Pokemon FireRed.zip ROM Hackers GBA Tool Pack roms send
eros_cope.png senderos_FM.png Thumbs.db Tileset0.bmp Tileset0.pal untitled.
bmp untitled.PNG wdps 3
```

I have a feeling that this is some kind of windows thing, or am I missing something critical here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem of \* in Command line argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718873/problem-of-in-command-line-argument)

Comment: You can fix your code by using `GetCommandLine()` instead of `argv`, though note that this will also include the executable.  (That is, it will return `a 2 ** 3` rather than `2 ** 3`.)

Comment: I had a feeling there would be a complicated way to get this to work. I guess a few ifdef's aren't so horrible, but I hate using windows.h ;_;
Thank you for pointing that out, I wasn't aware that was an actual function, as it seems a little bit unnecessary beyond weirdly specific use-cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**` is a classic "wildcard" in many shells, windows included.. It will be replaced with a list of all files in the current directory.

Therefore, you can do `del *` to delete all files.  Using multiple *'s is the same as single *'s.

Comment: Huh, I'd known about a single asterisk, but never heard of the double asterisk being a wildcard. Thanks! (:

Comment: This is incorrect; the Windows shell does *not* do any such replacement.  The executable itself is responsible for doing so if appropriate.  Typically this is handled by the runtime library.

Comment: Are you saying that GCC's CRT is responsible for replacing ** with the directory listing? If that were the case, wouldn't it make more sense for it to adopt the linux wildcard [ a single asterisk? ] I feel pretty confident that my code isn't doing that, and I tried running `del **.exe` and it worked well enough. Can you explain a little bit more what you mean when you say it's handled by the runtime library?