# java Application 23 * 2 sending "23 * 2" as argument. why am i getting "args.length" = 7?

Tags: java

java Application 23 * 2

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(args.length);
}
```

output: 7

why?

Comment: You should take time to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why dont you print the args `for(String s: args){ System.out.println("arg: " + s); }`

Comment: Is that your complete command line? `23 * 2` will be parsed by most shells as arguments `"23"` `"*"` and `"2"` but your shell seems different...

Comment: I'm out of votes, but here's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718873/problem-of-in-command-line-argument

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you would get what you're expecting.

On Linux, the command shell is applying wildcard expansion, replacing the `*` with names of all the files in the current directory.

To prevent wildcard expansion, quote the parameter (from [Stop shell wildcard character expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion)):

```
java Application 23 '*' 2
```

Comment: or possibly the OP wants java Application '23 * 2' - that is, a single argument to main