# Why does this Java code print two arguments?

Tags: java, linux, bash

The below Java code prints two arguments when I pass `!clear` as input as shown below.

```
class Test{

    public static void main(final String... arguments){
        for(String argument : arguments){
            System.out.println(argument);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
$ java Test !clear
java Test clear
clear
```

**UPDATE**

Using any linux command in place of `clear` produces the same result.

```
$ java Test !pwd
java Test pwd
pwd

$ java Test !ls
java Test ls
ls
```

I am aware that this has got something to do with history expansion in bash and I can escape the ! character to solve this issue.

However, I am curious to know the exact reason why this code prints the above two lines as output. Could somebody please explain?

Comment: [this can help you for understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2718887/2749470)

Comment: @P.An You're describing `$`, not `!`. `$foo` does variable expansion. `!foo` does history expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working within a Unix/Linux shell, probably `bash`. The `!` character is a special character in the Unix shell, and thus your command is considered a history expansion.

In history expansion, the usual thing that happens is that the shell shows you what the command expands to. The expansion of `!clear` will simply be `clear` **provided that you had the command `clear` in your history**, and the expanded command will therefore be `java Test clear`. The shell then *runs* the command. Java runs and only sees one argument - `clear`, and that's what it prints.

If instead, you run

```
java Test '!clear'
```

(With the single quotes!)

Java will get the argument `!clear` as is, without history expansion.

If you use a word that is not in the shell's history of commands, you'll get an "event not found error". If you use a word that, in your shell history, started a command with arguments, the entire command with all its arguments will be substituted. This is all part of `bash` and not Java.

Comment: Yes, I am aware I can escape the input to solve the issue. Thanks for your explanation. So, the first line is not printed by Java.

Comment: However, when I type !clear in my bash, I don't see anything printed, it just clears the screen. Why is it so?

Comment: @Beginner because when the `!` precedes the first word in the command, it is looking for a command in the history that starts with this word, and recalls it. If you had a command that starts with the word `clear`, the shell would recall that. And since it clears the screen, you'll hardly have the opportunity to see if it prints anything or not.

Comment: Sorry, I am not still understanding it right. Even if shell calls `clear` why would clear print anything?

Comment: @Beginner `clear` will not print anything. The shell is set to print the recalled command before executing it. But because the recalled command clears any printing, I don't think the print will be visible.

Comment: I just tried `java Test !pwd` and get the same result. So, I think it's not related to usage of `clear`

Comment: @Beginner you talked about `clear` in the *beginning* of the line. Only there it has a significance as a command. In any case, we can't continue this discussion in the comments. Please read a `bash` tutorial or book for further information.